# Testing a Jekyll site with rspec and capybara, getting a bizarre race-case on rspec start

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, jekyll

So check this out: it *appears* as though, upon running `bundle exec rspec`, there's a race between `jekyll serve` and puma/rspec's boot up. Sometimes I run the command, and my tests run fine. Other times, I get the error for each of my spec files: `cannot load such file -- /path/to/project/sitename_jekyll/_layouts/spec/form_spec.rb` which is interesting cause that's not where my spec files are located. They're in /path/to/project/sitename_jekyll/spec/form_spec.rb.

What's crazy is that I can literally just re-run the command over and over and over again and sometimes it'll go through and run the spec tests in the correct location, and sometimes it'll look for them in _layouts and error out. It probably runs correctly maybe once out of ever three or five attempts. All the other times I get the following errors:

Here's what my spec_helper.rb looks like: https://gist.github.com/johnhutch/2cddfafcde0485ff021501d5696c0c2d

And here's an example test file:
https://gist.github.com/johnhutch/a35d15c170f5fd9ca07998bf035d111d

My .rspec only contains two lines:
    --color
    --require spec_helper

And here's the output, both successful and unsuccesful, back to back: 
https://gist.github.com/johnhutch/7927d609170ef5c70a595735502b128d

HEEELLLLLP!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you create two `Capybara::Selenium::Driver` instances in your `:headless_chrome` driver registration?

Comment: On a side note -- your example test file really isn't actually testing anything since `has_xxx?` just returns true or false and therefore won't ever cause the test to fail - you should be doing `expect(page).to have_css(...)` - etc.

Comment: re: two instances -- just a hold-over from my debugging, testing various parts of the config to see what caused the issue.

Comment: re: example test is very literally just an example cause I had to remove some identifying info from the tests. The real tests are much more robust, I promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like jekyll is changing the current directory while building the site, which since it is being run in a thread also affects the tests RSpec is trying to run (See https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9785 for why `Dir.chdir` is not threadsafe) - leading to attempts to load things from incorrect locations.

A potential solution to this would be to wait for the Jekyll site to be built before actually running your tests. A comment in your `spec_helper` seems to state that someone thought passing `force_build: true` would do this but from a quick perusal of the `jekyll-rack` code I don't think that's true and you actually need to wait for `compiling?` to return false (v 0.5) (`complete?` to return true in the current master branch) to ensure building has finished (as well as passing `force_build`).  This could either be done in a loop sleeping and checking (simpler)

```
sleep 0.1 while <jekyll app>.compiling?
```

or (if using the master branch) via the mutex/conditional Rack::Jekyll exposes like in its test suite - https://github.com/adaoraul/rack-jekyll/blob/master/test/helper.rb#L49

Note: Also check my comment about your tests that aren't actually testing anything.

Comment: You are a lovely, wonderful, intelligent person who should be showered with gifts and accolades. Ima start digging into your suggestions immediately and report back on how it goes.

Comment: Ok, I'm at a loss. I don't have a deep enough understanding of jekyll-rack to apply your advice and I keep hitting walls as I try go plow my was through.

I first tried via the mutex/conditional in the jekyll-rack test suite. No luck there. Here's a gist of my changes, and the result: https://gist.github.com/johnhutch/81d557cb49efa2c67efaefae69fa13f1

Then I tried the more simple solution: https://gist.github.com/johnhutch/98f6c6a3e66c630d36ba954968e80ce9

Still no dice :(

I feel like a greedy help vampire to ask for more help, but if you have minute, I'd be super appreciative!

Comment: @JohnHutch You may need to be running the master branch of `rack-jekyll` for  that to work - just loop with a small sleep (.1 or so) until jekyll.compiling? is false with the release version (0.5) I think

Comment: @JohnHutch I assume you noticed I edited my answer and changed to `compiling?` and that it will be false when done -- When the master branch was changed to use a mutex it also replaced `compiling?` with `completed?`- https://github.com/adaoraul/rack-jekyll/commit/65487d97e0d9be849ae9a61d7b18aea84e56b84d

Comment: You beautiful, wonderful genius person. It worked! Specifically: 
sleep 0.1 while Capybara.app.compiling?

Comment: @John Hutch If this answer is helpful then please accept the answer, there is a hallow tic below the down vote symbol which you need to click and it would turn out to green after your click.

Answer (score 0):

As per Thomas Walpole's super helpful responses this ended up working:

sleep 0.1 while Capybara.app.compiling?

inserted right after:

51   Capybara.app = Rack::Jekyll.new(force_build: true)

in my spec_helper.rb

Thanks again, Thomas!